# Dual boot redirecting to windows 10 instead or OS choice

Tags: software-installation, dual-boot

I had windows 10 in my lenovo V110 laptop, Legacy BIOS.
Then I installed Loki alongside windows in another XFS drive. Now after installation, whenever I start my computer, windows 10 opens directly instead of OS choice prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simpliest way is using **Boot-Repair** utility.

You can find the instructions on official [website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
There are several options such as preparing bootable stick with special image, or installing it on live session and using from there.

P.S.: be careful with *advanced options*.